# Page width in Mobile/iOs

Tags: css, mobile

I have read the related posts; 'Mobile CSS Page Width - etc' but haven't found a solution.

I've developed a mobile version of a website, and the width fills fine in Android, and Blackberry - but, for some reason in iPhone there remains extra space on the sides of the content, making the site render slightly smaller in content area and with more background. When a user double taps - it then, takes the full screen as it does in Android & Blackberry.

Any suggestions?

I've tried declaring the doc mobile, and using the '`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` ' but it then zooms in the site way too much (Should I try toggling the 'initial-scale')?

I've tried the basics as well with setting to liquid etc.

Can't I use similar script, as I've used with Mobile Redirects to define how widths could render per device?

```
<!--Script for Mobile Redirect -->  

<script type="text/javascript">

var redirectagent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var redirect_devices = ['vnd.wap.xhtml+xml', 'sony', 'symbian', 'nokia', 'samsung', 'mobile', 'windows ce', 'epoc', 'opera mini', 'nitro', 'j2me', 'midp-', 'cldc-', 'netfront', 'mot', 'up.browser', 'up.link', 'audiovox', 'blackberry', 'ericsson', 'panasonic', 'philips', 'sanyo', 'sharp', 'sie-', 'portalmmm', 'blazer', 'avantgo', 'danger', 'palm', 'series60', 'palmsource', 'pocketpc', 'smartphone', 'rover', 'ipaq', 'au-mic', 'alcatel', 'ericy', 'vodafone', 'wap1', 'wap2', 'teleca', 'playstation', 'lge', 'lg-', 'iphone', 'android', 'htc', 'dream', 'webos', 'bolt', 'nintendo'];
for (var i in redirect_devices) {
if (redirectagent.indexOf(redirect_devices[i]) != -1) {
location.replace("http://www.osmproduction.com/crown/maxbrooks/Test/MobileZombie/index.html");
}
}
</script>

<!--End Script for mobile Redirect -->
```

**Sub-question:** Can anyone give me advice on best practices for optimizing for Blackberry - The page is rendering super zoomed in a certain Blackberry Model now (Don't recall Model, but 2007)- I'm assuming this discussion to take the width per device should tackle this issue as well, right? Or is developing for Blackberries somewhat of a separate issue? and something I'd have to look at separately as they kind of suck for browsing?

Comment: Anyone have thoughts on this, and the different default page views mobile devices have? What's a best practice for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<meta name="viewport" content="width=800">` where 800 is the amount of pixels that will fit your layout. By default iPhone uses 980, so if your page has a fixed width of 800px you would get 180px of blank space around it.

Comment: Very helpful - I'm gonna give that a shot tomorrow at work when I can get my hands on an iPhone.

Comment: So this solved the iPhone display - Thanks! But still at a loss with taking the width in BlackBerry.

Comment: What size does BB use? Just set it to that size.

Comment: How? I want to keep the one that works well with iPhone and Android - is there a way to set a Blackberry Conditial that will trigger the Meta I set for BB width? I think another concern with BB is - the interfaces makes the user zoom twice before accessing content/or clicking links.

Comment: Is BB rendering so much differently that iphone/android that you need a different page width? I find that very strange.

Comment: No - it seems the actual problem (at this point) is not the site taking the width. It appears to render fine width wise in BB. But BB requires a zoom (With that annoying magnifying glass icon) before being able to access links or pretty much any browsing - I guess ultimately, how do I remove that zoom and have the site completely accessible via the cursor (ie; Click > Links > Done)

Comment: Oh and the BB width is 480px - if helps the discussion.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following META-tag. It seems to work fine with my tests:

```
<META name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

This will scale to the width of the device, no matter what size it is.

Comment: Cool - I'm gonna give this a shot tomorrow too. I'll let you guys know how it turns out. Why is it Android seems to take the widths better then iPhone?

Comment: Note that with this solution you have to redesign your page to also look good if the width of the page is only 320px. It removes the need to zoom and pan entirely, which is good, but takes some extra work.

Comment: @Gerben, Yes. That is true. Hence, Most of my features works with % sizes eg. header `width:100%;` so it fits all well.